# Jquery: Checking to see if div contains text, then action

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check in jQuery if a div contains some text, and then add a class if it does.

So I wrote something like this:

```
    if( $("#field > div.field-item").text().indexOf('someText') = 0) {
        $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
    }
```

I'm not getting this to work.

```
<div id="field"><div class="field-item">someText</div></div>

<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Your code contains two problems:

- The equality operator in JavaScript is `==`, not `=`.
- `jQuery.text()` joins all text nodes of matched elements into a single string. If you have two successive elements, of which the first contains `'some'` and the second contains `'Text'`, then your code will incorrectly think that there exists an element that contains `'someText'`.

I suggest the following instead:

```
if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
    $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

Comment: I have two type text "Follow" & "Following" in divs. how to find exact text with divs. 
example. 5 divs with "Follow" & 2 divs with "Following" out put showing 7 for "Follow" & 2 for "Following"

Answer (score 18):

Yes, I now made think for me. And it works fine!!!

```
if($("div:contains('CONGRATULATIONS')").length)
                        {
                            $('#SignupForm').hide(500);
                        }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if( $("#field > div.field-item").text().indexOf('someText') >= 0)
```

Some browsers will include whitespace, others won't.  `>=` is appropriate here.  Otherwise equality is double equals `==`

Answer (score 5):

Ayman is right but, you can use it like that as well :

```
if( $("#field > div.field-item").text().indexOf('someText') >= 0) {
        $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply

```
var item = $('.field-item');
for (var i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
       if ($(item[i]).text() == 'someText') {
             $(item[i]).addClass('thisClass');
             //do some other stuff here
          }
     }
```

Comment: not valid response, . is to select a class, not a div id

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the `contains` selector:

```
if ($("#field > div.field-item:contains('someText')").length) {
    $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

Also, as other mentioned, you must use == or === rather than =.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla Javascript solution in 2020:

```js
const fieldItem = document.querySelector('#field .field-item')
if (fieldItem.innerText.includes('someText')) {
  fieldItem.classList.add('red')
  console.log(fieldItem)
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div class="field-item">someText</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work and is case insensitive

```
function has_text(selector, text){
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return selector.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1
}

// for test
var exists = has_text($('#test_id'), 'hello');
console.log(exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="field"><div class="field-item">someText</div></div>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

JS

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 if ($('div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {

$('div#somediv').append("<p>someText was there, so class 'thisClass' was added").addClass("thisClass")
.css("border","2px red");
  }
});
```

JSfiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/Loqctuaf/