# jQuery if, .addClass()

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains, addclass

Im trying to add a class to another element if an element contains text.

So let's say I have a `<td>` classified as `vCSS_breadcrumb_td`. How can I check is the `<td>` contains a word, and if it does contain that word, add a class to an `<a>` classified is `nav1`.

I know that I could probably make use of the `:contains` selector, I just don't know how to write an if statement

Comment: [Read about `if` statements in the MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action Check out this question, seems similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('.vCSS_breadcrumb_td:contains("word")').length) {
    $('.nav1').addClass('class');
}
```

You need to check the `length` property, since jQuery always returns an Array-like object.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if ($("td.vCSS_breadcrumb_td").text().length)
    $("a.nav1").addClass("someClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
    $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

Copied from [Jquery: Checking to see if div contains text, then action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action) and posted as answer

Comment: If you think that an answer of another question can answer this question, you should make a comment and point this out (because then the question is a duplicate). Don't copy other answers. At least you gave credit which is good :)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you already made a comment... you need 3000 rep for voting a question to close.