# Accessing child elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="1">
   <div>contents..</div>
   <div>contents..</div>
 </div>
 <div id="2">
   <div>contents..</div>
   <div>contents..</div>
 </div>
 <div id="3">
   <div>contents..</div>
   <div>contents..</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can i access all `div object` into a single array who have `contents in there innerHTML`?

**EDIT**

OK I tried this :

```
var totaldiv = $("#main").children();
var totalElements = [];
var c = 0;
$.each(totaldiv, function (i, v) {
    $(totaldiv[i]).children().each(function () {
        totalElements[c++] = $(this);
    });
});
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: **ANY** content or exactly the string **contents..** ?? And please... what `DIV` exactly, the parent DIV or the one that holds some text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
var divArr = $('#main div > div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html();  // return those div not empty, has text or html element
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/qam7n/)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to exclude the higher level elements - if you use `.text()` on its own you'll get every element that contains text *anywhere* below it, not just in child nodes:

```
var haveContent = $('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0 && $.trim($(this).text()) !== '';
}).get();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WNKLA/

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic, the following will match your example above:

```
$('#main div div');
```

Assuming there are div elements who may not have any text content, you could try this:

```
$('#main div div').contents().filter(function(){ return this.length > 0; })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents()` to access all div contents in there innerhtml..

```
var arry = $('div:contains(contents)');
```

check this link;

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

And

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

And check this one.. It is similar to your question

[Jquery: Checking to see if div contains text, then action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action)