# Search text on inserted DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a simple script for detecting changes in the DOM, and then performing some actions.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#entry', function() {
// check if inserted element contains text, then run function
})
```

What is the simplest way of search text on the inserted DOM node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: Checking to see if div contains text, then action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action)

Comment: I would imagine a simple indexOf would do the trick: `console.log(insertedElement.val().indexOf("my text to check") > -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of the passed in event object within the handler and perform a check using methods such as `indexOf()` or similar to determine if the text you are looking for is present.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var $targetElement = $(e.target);

    if($targetElement.text().indexOf('Test') > -1) {
        console.log('foo');
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/771yboon/3/) demonstrating a simple check of inserted elements' text using `text()` and `indexOf()`.