# jQuery check span class and hide closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having quite a bit of trouble figuring out why this function is not working properly. I have tried using `.html` `val` `trim` `!` `:contains' '.text` and other variations to test the string inside a span with a specific class but the console seems to return the object correctly however fails. Any help is appreciated.

```js
if (jQuery('.price').text() == '') {
  jQuery(this).closest(".box").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  test content<br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content<br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content<br>
  <span class="price"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content<br>
  <span class="price"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content<br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your working code with HTML

Comment: Yeah, it won't work because you have no HTML.

Comment: You've told us it doesn't work, but not said what you're actually trying to do, or shown us enough code to solve any issues

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/902621/4673847

Comment: ... Obviously there is a span with class .price inside a div with class .box. Dont down vote just because you cant figure it out, the code looks solid if i put jQuery('.price').closest(".box").hide(); they will all hide the html is irrelevant it is in the if statement and the "this" use that is not functioning properly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qajLjmkd/1/

Comment: Thank you for adding the information to the question - it was the HTML we needed to see in order to help you. I added an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is because you're retrieving the `text()` from *all* the `.price` elements at once. You instead need to loop through them and check the text individually, and then hide the related `.box`, like this:

```js
$('.price').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == '') {
    $(this).closest('.box').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  test content
  <br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content
  <br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content
  <br>
  <span class="price"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content
  <br>
  <span class="price"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  test content
  <br>
  <span class="price">$99.99</span>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS YOu!!!!!! Amazing :D your the best thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your need to loop true each element.

```
$('.price').each( function(index) {
  if ($(this).text() == "") {
    $(this).closest(".box").hide();
  }
});
```

But you have a problem with your HTML. Because there are 2 close neighbors with the class `.box`

Answer (score -1):

I am not getting your exact requirement. Try below code may be will help you.

```
if (jQuery('.price').text() != '') {
  jQuery('.price').closest(".box").hide();
}
```

Comment: this will hide all the listings, I only need listings with no price displayed. This is why im trying to check all spans that have a class .price, check if it is empty, then hide that specific span's closest divider with .box class to hide it from showing