# How to disable some post links on WordPress Category Page?

Tags: wordpress

I've been searching here an from other sources for a solution and can't find any. Maybe I'm approaching this wrong.

I have a group of posts, all tied together via a common category. On the default listing page for that category I need to disable the link on some of the posts in the list while leaving the link active for others.

Is there a way to keep all posts of a category shown on the listing page while disabling the links on just some of them?

I've got to believe there's probably some simple and obvious way to do this but I'm not finding it. Or maybe there's a better/different approach to what I'm trying to accomplish?

TIA

Comment: I would use JavaScript to delete the links on page load.

Comment: How would you target some links while leaving others alone?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action

Comment: @meck373 So, the answer you refer to offer this,

    `if ($('#field > div.field-item:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
        $("#somediv").addClass("thisClass");
    }`

Do I understand correctly the "field" in this code is looking at a field in my WordPress database. So, I would need to create a custom field which would be used as a trigger to facilitate this solution?